# How to convert SQL text file to SQL script?

Tags: sql, encoding, mysql-workbench

I have exported an SQL text file with an older version of MySQL workbench. Now I m trying to import it in new version of MySQL Workbench, but it either shows encoding error or shows empty database. When I tried to open the file with text editor (in Notepad++) it shows [NULL][NULL][NULL]...............35 times. What to do?

P.S. When I was working on older version I have made a backup to my exported SQL file after checking it many times, so it can't be corrupted or empty by mistake.

Here's a link to my SQL file.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tgr15kWEhOEon0FCyJJcpqDwKTv0IweM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: That google drive link just shows an empty file.

Comment: I dont know why, It is the original file that i used to work on, now its showing nothing.

Comment: Try to open it with Notepad++

Comment: Is the SQLite tag there by accident? MySQL Workbench rather indicates MySQL? Please edit the tags.

Comment: Ya, sorry it was  by mistake

Comment: Is the old database still existing? That file you have is utterly useless, just some null bytes. That won't create any database. Maybe retry the export and if it fails again describe exactly what you do to export.